# Transforming a dataframe of dict of dict specific format

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, xgboost

I have this `df` dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'train': {'auc': [0.432,       0.543,       0.523],
  'logloss': [0.123,       0.234,       0.345]},
 'test': {'auc': [0.456,       0.567,       0.678],
  'logloss': [0.321,       0.432,       0.543]}})
```

[image]

Where I'm trying to transform it into this:

[image]

And also considering that:

- `epochs` always have the same order for every cell, but instead of only 3 epochs, it could reach 1.000 or 10.000.
- The column names and axis could change. For example another day the data could have `f1` instead of `logloss`, or `val` instead of `train`. But no matter the names, in `df` each row will always be a metric name, and each column will always be a dataset name.
- The number of columns and rows in `df` could change too. There are some models with 5 datasets, and 7 metrics for example (which would give a `df` with 5 columns and 7 rows)
- The columname of the output table should be `datasetname_metricname`

So I'm trying to build some generic code transformation where at the same time avoiding brute force transformations. Just if it's helpful, the `df` source is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(model_xgb.evals_result())
df.columns = ['train', 'test'] # This is the line that can change (and the metrics inside `model_xgb`)
```

Where `model_xgb = xgboost.XGBClassifier(..)`, but after using `model_xgb.fit(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic way to get the result you've specified, irrespective of the number of epochs or the number or labels of rows and columns:

```py
df2 = df.stack().apply(pd.Series)
df2.index = ['_'.join(reversed(x)) for x in df2.index]
df2 = df2.T.assign(epochs=range(1, len(df2.columns) + 1)).set_index('epochs').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   epochs  train_auc  test_auc  train_logloss  test_logloss
0       1      0.432     0.456          0.123         0.321
1       2      0.543     0.567          0.234         0.432
2       3      0.523     0.678          0.345         0.543
```

Explanation:

- Use `stack()` to convert the input dataframe to a series (of lists) with a multiindex that matches the desired column sequence in the question
- Use `apply(pd.Series)` to convert the series of lists to a dataframe with each list converted to a row and with column count equal to the uniform length of the list values in the input series (in other words, equal to the number of epochs)
- Create the desired column labels from the latest multiindex rows transformed using `join()` with `_` as a separator, then use `T` to transpose the dataframe so these index labels (which are the desired column labels) become column labels
- Use `assign()` to add a column named `epochs` enumerating the epochs beginning with `1`
- Use `set_index()` followed by `reset_index()` to make `epochs` the leftmost column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'train': {'auc': [0.432,       0.543,       0.523],
  'logloss': [0.123,       0.234,       0.345]},
 'test': {'auc': [0.456,       0.567,       0.678],
  'logloss': [0.321,       0.432,       0.543]}})

de=df.explode(['train', 'test'])
df_out = de.set_index(de.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1, append=True).unstack(0)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'epochs'})
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   epochs train_auc train_logloss test_auc test_logloss
0       1     0.432         0.123    0.456        0.321
1       2     0.543         0.234    0.567        0.432
2       3     0.523         0.345    0.678        0.543
```